# Find the measure of $|AB|$

Tags: geometry

In the figure, $ABCD$ is a rectangle with $|DE|=|EC|,|BC|=9cm,$ and $|BF|=10cm.$ Find $|AB|.$

[image]

Help me please. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[image: Rectangle ABCD]

$$\frac { \left| DF \right|  }{ \left| FB \right|  } =\frac { \left| DE \right|  }{ \left| AB \right|  } \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac { \left| DF \right|  }{ 10 } =\frac { \left| DE \right|  }{ 2\left| DE \right|  } \Rightarrow \left| DF \right| =5\\ \left| AB \right| =\sqrt { { 15 }^{ 2 }-{ 9 }^{ 2 } } =12\quad $$

Comment: You were two and a half seconds faster than I ;)

Comment: Ah, much better formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: 12

Given:

1. DE = EC = 9cm; therefore AB = 2 * DE
2. AD = BC, because rectangle.

Procedure:

1. Triangle ABF is similar to triangle EDF, because line AB is parallel to line ED.
2. Following proportionality of similar triangles, ED:AB :: DF:FB
3. Since AB = 2 * DE, DF = 0.5 * BF.
4. Hypotenuse BD = BF + FD = 10 + 5 = 15.
5. We have a right-angled triangle DAB, with hypotenuse = 15, one side = 9. Apply pythagorus theorem, to get AB = 12